# Shift/reduce conflict in yacc due to look-ahead token limitation?

Tags: parsing, yacc, conflict, shift-reduce

I've been trying to tackle a seemingly simple shift/reduce conflict with no avail. Naturally, the parser works fine if I just ignore the conflict, but I'd feel much safer if I reorganized my rules. Here, I've simplified a relatively complex grammar to the single conflict:

```
statement_list
  : statement_list statement 
  | 
  ;

statement
  : lvalue '=' expression
  | function
  ;

lvalue
  : IDENTIFIER
  | '(' expression ')'
  ;

expression
  : lvalue
  | function
  ;

function
  : IDENTIFIER '(' ')'
  ;
```

With the verbose option in yacc, I get this output file describing the state with the mentioned conflict:

```
state 2

    lvalue  ->  IDENTIFIER .   (rule 5)
    function  ->  IDENTIFIER . '(' ')'   (rule 9)

    '('  shift, and go to state 7

    '('  [reduce using rule 5 (lvalue)]
    $default reduce using rule 5 (lvalue)
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that this requires 2-token lookahead to know when it has reached the end of a statement.  If you have input of the form:

```
ID = ID ( ID ) = ID
```

after parser shifts the second ID (lookahead is `(`), it doesn't know whether that's the end of the first statement (the `(` is the beginning of a second statement), or this is a function.  So it shifts (continuing to parse a function), which is the wrong thing to do with the example input above.

If you extend `function` to allow an argument inside the parenthesis and `expression` to allow actual expressions, things become worse, as the lookahead required is unbounded -- the parser needs to get all the way to the second `=` to determine that this is not a function call.

The basic problem here is that there's no helper punctuation to aid the parser in finding the end of a statement.  Since text that is the beginning of a valid statement can also appear in the middle of a valid statement, finding statement boundaries is hard.

Comment: I hadn't considered such an input. Well, the language I'm parsing requires such ambiguity so I suppose I will just ignore the conflict.